# Emacs with Python Code Completion > Code Completion Suggestions Not Popping Up

Tags: python, emacs, code-completion

After installing:

```
[rope]
[ropemode]
[pymacs]
[ropemacs]
[autocomplete 1.3.1]
```

And configuring `.emacs`:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/autocomplete1.3.1")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/share/emacs/lisp/")

(setq py-install-directory "~/share/emacs/lisp/")
(require 'python-mode)

(autoload 'pymacs-apply "pymacs")
(autoload 'pymacs-call "pymacs")
(autoload 'pymacs-eval "pymacs" nil t)
(autoload 'pymacs-exec "pymacs" nil t)
(autoload 'pymacs-load "pymacs" nil t)
(autoload 'pymacs-autoload "pymacs")

(require 'pymacs)
(pymacs-load "ropemacs" "rope-")
(setq ropemacs-enable-autoimport t)

(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/autocomplete1.3.1/ac-dict")
(ac-config-default)

(require 'auto-complete)
(global-auto-complete-mode t)
```

I typed a period after `sys.`, and hoped for code completion similar to Komodo Edit.

Unfortunately, the best I could achieve, was pressing **M-/** to bring up a split screen code completion buffer.

How does one achieve code completion in GNU Emacs, which is similar to  Komodo-Edit?

Here's a [pymacs bug](https://github.com/pinard/Pymacs/pull/29) bug that caught me out:

Comment: what version of emacs/platform?

Comment: **GNU Emacs 24.1.1** | **Ubuntu 12.04**

Any reason why the context menu wouldn't show?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the definition of `ac-config-default` as it is the only thing you do to configure AC:

```
(defun ac-config-default ()
  (setq-default ac-sources '(ac-source-abbrev ac-source-dictionary ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers))
  (add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'ac-emacs-lisp-mode-setup)
  (add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'ac-cc-mode-setup)
  (add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook 'ac-ruby-mode-setup)
  (add-hook 'css-mode-hook 'ac-css-mode-setup)
  (add-hook 'auto-complete-mode-hook 'ac-common-setup)
  (global-auto-complete-mode t))
```

There is no Python config, so you can't expect AC to work for Python.

To set it up:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'ac-ropemacs-setup)
```

Shameless plug: Here are alternate ropemacs sources for AC - as the included source does not show documentation: https://github.com/cofi/dotfiles/blob/master/emacs.d/config/cofi-python.el#L75

Here again to configure:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda ()
                              (setq ac-source (append ac-source '(ac-source-nropemacs
                                                                  ac-source-nropemacs-dot)))))
```